# FlashPunk: How to get that classic Jaggy Edge on Rotated Sprites?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, antialiasing

It seems like even if you set an Image object's **smooth** property to **false**, it doesn't make the Bitmap look jaggy on non-90-degree angles (jaggy = aliased, opposite of a smooth edges = anti-aliased).

Is there any way to achieve this? Or do I have to construct the rotation-spritesheet by hand and interpret the "angles to sprite index" calculations myself?

Comment: you meant the flash.display.Bitmap.smoothing property, right?  if so, are you trying to set this property in AS3 or in the properties settings of the library asset in Flash Professional IDE?

Comment: Nope, in some FlashPunk-based games you'll notice that the edges of rotated sprites stays jaggy. This has to do with the StageQuality set to LOW. Bitmap.smoothing is a slightly different option, as (when enabled) it tends to "blur" all the content of a Bitmap, giving it a polished look even when rotated, scaled or skewed. Although it's true both Stage.quality and Bitmap.smoothing, when turned LOW / false, they don't perform any edge smoothing or blurring algorithms on the content which can give your sprites an 8-bit style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM;
```

or

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
```

do what your want?  I haven't used this in a very long time, but tweaking quality is an old-school way to improve performance during certain situations.

Comment: Hmm I'll give it a shot but I don't believe the Bitmap processing in FlashPunk takes the Stage Quality into account, it's a different topic.

Comment: stage.quality sets how things get rendered on the screen, and not how the various classes work.  FlashPunk sets this to HIGH (see Engine.as line 126 in the latest tarball), and you should be able to override setStageProperties() in your app.

Comment: I'm not sure if setting it directly to "stage.quality = ..." works, but via the "FP.stage.quality = ..." does work indeed :)